# errors with AndroidStudio and BoundBox

Tags: android, android-studio, boundbox

BoundBox is working fine with gradle in my android project - just AndroidStudio does not pick up the generated classes. Is there a way to make them play well together so that AndroidStudio is aware of the BoundBoxOf* classes?